# pyarrow throws ArrowNotImplementedError when creating table from numpy array

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

This code attempts to create a `pyarrow` table to store it in `parquet`, but get an error when converting from `numpy` array. What is this error and how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

array = np.array(
    [
        [1.1, 1.2, 1.4],
        [1, 2, 5],
        ['a', 'b', 'c']
    ]
)

fields = [pa.field('field1',pa.float64()),
          pa.field('field2',pa.int64()),
          pa.field('field3',pa.string())]

array_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(array, schema=pa.schema(fields))
```

from_arrays throws:

```
ArrowNotImplementedError: NumPy type not implemented: unrecognized type (19) in GetNumPyTypeName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy array can't have heterogeneous types (int, float string in the same array). So in this case the array is of type type `<U32` (a little-endian Unicode string of 32 characters, in other word string).

```
>>> array.dtype
dtype('<U32')
```

So the ints and floats get converted to string, and arrow would have to convert hte strings back to int, float respectively.

But Arrow is unable to convert from numpy string to int and float:

```
pa.array(np.array([1,2,3], dtype='<U32'), pa.int32())
>>> NumPy type not implemented: unrecognized type (19) in GetNumPyTypeName
```

Instead you should have one array for each column in your table, each of their own type, and it should work:

```
arrays =     [
        np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.4]),
        np.array([1, 2, 5]),
        np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    ]


fields = [pa.field('field1',pa.float64()),
          pa.field('field2',pa.int64()),
          pa.field('field3',pa.string())]

array_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(arrays, schema=pa.schema(fields))
```